# SalesForce - Find all children of a parent campaign

Tags: sql, salesforce

How do I find all of the child campaigns of a selected campaign via the REST API?

Do I have to run a specific query or is there a way to access the related list?

Comment: There's a field called ParentId that stores the Id of the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SOQL query to retrieve the child campaign details:

```
Select Id from Campaign where ParentId = '701i00000000000AAA'
```

Add whatever additional fields you need to the query. See also: [Execute a SOQL Query](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_query.htm)

If you prefer, you can reverse the SOQL query to follow the child relationships from the parent campaign.

```
Select Id, (Select Id from ChildCampaigns) from Campaign where Id = '701i00000000000AAA'
```

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: Is ChildCampaigns a standard SF database table?

Comment: ChildCampaigns is the name of the relationship created by ParentId. 
It shows up in the childRelationships metadata for Campaign.ParentId.